# How to catch empty QuerySnapShot with Firestore python API?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

## Context

I would like to fetch some data from Firestore that way:

```py
query = db.collection("users").where("age", ">", 20)

for document in query.stream():
    print("User id: {}".format(document.id))
```

However, I cannot assert whether it will iterate over documents. Indeed, if no documents match with my `where` condition, nothing happens. I would like to raise an Exception instead.

## Question

How can we catch any empty [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/query.html) with the python API ?

Resources: [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries)

Comment: I have the same question. You solve?

Comment: I ended up testing the result of the operations that should have happened in the `for` loop. Thank you for your answer tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve in this way:

```
documents = [d for d in db.collection("users").where("age", ">", 20).stream()]

if len(documents):
    for document in documents:
        print("User id: {}".format(document.id))
else:
    print('empty query')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
db.collection("users").where("age", ">", 20)
```

returns null if no document match with your where, please check for

if query!= null :
    for document in quer`enter code here`y.stream():
        print("User id: {}".format(document.id))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't think it is relevant. I'm using the python library, not the js one. Therefore, the return value is a [generator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator), not `null`as you suggested. Moreover, `null` does not exist in python.